# Typescript recursive string literals

Tags: typescript

I want to get the union of all they keys of my object recursively that is separated by period.

For example:

```
type User = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    work: {
        company: string;
        position: string;
    }
}
```

I want to get `'name' | 'age' | 'work' | 'work.company' | 'work.position'`;

This is my initial code:

```
type RecursiveKeys<T> = T extends number | string | boolean ? T : {[K in keyof T]: `${K}.${RecursiveKeys<T[K]>}`}[keyof T]
```

I suspect my mistake is in this part of my code `T extends number | string | boolean`. I'm not sure what condition shall I put to end my recursive

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for more information.  The solution looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpnbgw)

Comment: Its not perfect. It gives me this error `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`